# establishing connection between android app and database on google cloud

Tags: android, android-studio, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

i want to create an android application which simply inserts data in a database and gets data from it. Database is hosted on google cloud mysql. I am very much confused about how to connect my front end to my back end database as there are so many results on google like using app engine, endpoints, jdbc etc. Can someone please clarify the concept to me and how to establish the connection

Comment: If you have any flexibility about not using a Google Cloud MySQL database, you'd likely be much happier with a solution like Firebase instead of trying to understand general client-server communications.

Comment: thanks but according to my needs firebase is not an option. if you could help.!

Comment: It's a big topic

Comment: okay no problem. thank you